# Filtering dates in SQL such as "next year", "one week ago"

Tags: database, date, datetime, sqlite

I have a table and need to filter out those days which are 10 days less than today's date, and no longer than a month from today's date. However the dates are written in formats such as:

```
Last Thursday
A month ago
Two weeks ago
24 days ago
```

I am using SQLite3 and have been trying with statements along the lines of (with all the other code, of course)

```
WHERE DATE('month', 1, available_from) > DATE('now')
```

But have had no luck. How would I go abouts tackling this? I imagine it has something to do with the way the dates are written, any help would be lovely thank you!

EDIT:
I have also thought about using cases, but have zero clue how to approach it in a scenario like this.

Comment: You have to convert these values into 'real' date values, and that requires [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

Comment: I think the better question is, I'm unsure of how to set up a case where I could catch all the possible scenarios as there are so many and was wondering if there was an efficient way of doing it besides typing them all out manually

Comment: Only you know what cases you have.

Comment: How does it even make sense to store “Last Thursday” in the database - do you have any other, absolute timestamp that is in reference to stored as well …?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basis of how you could use CASES :-

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS funnydates;
--CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS funnydates (datestore TEXT);
--INSERT INTO funnydates VALUES('Last Thursday');
--INSERT INTO funnydates VALUES('A month ago');
--INSERT INTO funnydates VALUES('Two weeks ago');
--INSERT INTO funnydates VALUES('24 days ago');
SELECT *, (datetimeinsecs - converteddate) AS difference FROM (
SELECT *, date('now'), strftime('%s','now') datetimeinsecs, strftime('%w','now') as currentdayofweek, 
    -- CREATE AND POPULATE SQL Day of the week number
    -- Not really of use just showing use of multiple cases for multiple columns
    CASE
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%sunday' THEN 0
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%MoNdAy' THEN 1
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%TUESDAY%' THEN 2
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%Wednesday%' THEN 3
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%thursday%' THEN 4
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%friday%' THEN 5
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%saturday%' THEN 6
        ELSE -1
    END AS sqldayofweeknumber,

   -- More along the lines of what could be done
    CASE 
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%Last%' AND datestore LIKE '%Thursday%' THEN 
             strftime('%s','now') - ((7 - (4 - strftime('%w','now') )) * (60 * 60 * 24))
        WHEN datestore LIKE '%Last%' AND datestore LIKE '%Friday%' THEN 
            strftime('%s','now') - ((7 - (5 - strftime('%w','now'))) * (60 *60 *24))
        WHEN datestore LIKE 'two weeks ago' THEN
            strftime('%s','now') - (2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
        ELSE 'not converted' 
    END AS converteddate
FROM funnydates) WHERE (datetimeinsecs - converteddate) > (1 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

- Initial Lines (comments) were for creating and populating the data.
- Note the outer (first) SELECT selects from data of the inner select (the difference column being added to show data is from outer select).
- The 1st CASE block is purely to show multiple CASE usage. i.e. the `sqldayofweeknumber` column serves no functional purpose.
- The 2nd CASE block shows a few scenarios being handled, the column generated being the time in seconds relative to the current time that the date description resolves to.
- ELSE would probably not be used.
- The final `WHERE` clause will only include the required rows (as shown) record older than 1 day (approximately). For 10 days then it would be `WHERE (datetimeinsecs - converteddate) > (10 * 24 * 60 * 60)`

Run using 1 day the result is :-

[image]

Run using 10 Days (`WHERE (datetimeinsecs - converteddate) > (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)`) :-

[image]
 i.e The **Last Thursday** row is less than after the 10 days ago cut of, so is excluded.

**Note, this is purely an in-principle example for demonstration. The entire solution would obviously be more complex.**

You may wish to reference :-

- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - **expression**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - **Date And Time Functions**](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)